# Intersection of sets within functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $S = \{1,2\} = T$ and define $f: S \to T$ by $f(1) = 1 = f(2)$. Let 
>   $B = \{1\}$ and let $C = \{2\}$. Find $f[B \cap C]$ and $f[B] \cap f[C]$.

I do not fully understand this, so obviously for the first one.
$B \cap C$ is an empty set since they have nothing in common between the two sets, so would the function just result in an empty set?  I am not sure how to compute the second one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the first part: $B\cap C=\emptyset$, and $f[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ regardless of what $f$ is.

Re: the second part, recall what "$f[X]$" means: it's $\{f(x): x\in X\}$. So $$f[B]=\{f(x): x\in B\}=\{f(1)\}$$ and $$f[C]=\{f(x): x\in C\}=\{f(2)\}.$$ Now:

- What is $f(1)$?
- What is $f(2)$?
- Now you've found $f[B]$ and $f[C]$; what's their intersection?